# Python: Detecting when an image collides with another image

Tags: python, pygame

I am making this game where you are moving a circle using the arrows keys and there is another circle spawning randomly on the screen. I want to make a piece of code to detect when the first circle collides with the second circle. I know that `collidepoint()` might come in useful but there is nothing else I really can do. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
    while True:
        #if image1 collides with image2
            Score -= 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Pygame supports collision detection between sprites using circles.

The API call you need is:

[`pygame.sprite.collide_circle()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

You can see an example of its use in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/81408/pygames-sprite-collide-circle-missing-several-frames-of-head-on-collision) on game dev SE (and don't worry - the bug that question is about has been fixed).

If for some reason you are not using sprites, then circle-circle collision detection is pretty straightforward: just test if the distance between them is less than the sum of their radii.
Or rather, test if the square of the distance between them is less than the square of the sum of their radii (to avoid slow square root calculation):

```
def circlesCollide(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2):
    return (((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2) < ((r1+r2)**2))
```

Note, that this assumes your circle is not moving fast enough to pass enitrely through the other circle in one update step, in which case you need to do a swept circle collision test.

Comment: The two circle are images, would this work in this case?

Comment: Create sprites for your game objects, and assign the images to these sprites, then this will work.

Comment: Do you have an example you could show me?

Comment: I've added a link to example for pygame.sprite.collide_circle(), and example code for your own test.